# Pd.to_datetime returns an object, not a time series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I am trying to convert my column in a df into a time series. The dataset  goes from March 23rd 2015-August 17th 2019 and the dataset looks like this:

```
                        time    1day_active_users
0  2015-03-23 00:00:00-04:00              19687.0
1  2015-03-24 00:00:00-04:00              19437.0
```

I am trying to convert the time column into a datetime series but it returns the column as an object. Here is the code:

```
data = pd.read_csv(data_path)
data.set_index('time', inplace=True)
data.index= pd.to_datetime(data.index)
data.index.dtype
```

data.index.dtype returns dtype('O'). I assume this is why when I try to index an element in time, it returns an error. For example, when I run this:

```
data.loc['2015']
```

It gives me this error

```
KeyError: '2015'
```

Any help or feedback would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am not able to duplicate your error.  What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: You are changing your index to datetime but you are trying to index by a year. Is that the issue?

Comment: My pandas version is 0.24.2. And yes the issue is I am trying to index by year or any date. Nothing I try to index will work.

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead and did that.

Comment: The problem is because the column contains different timezones.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As commented, the problem might be due to the different timezones. Try passing `utc=True` to `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],utc=True)
df['time']
```

Test Data

```
                        time  1day_active_users
0  2015-03-23 00:00:00-04:00            19687.0
1  2015-03-24 00:00:00-05:00            19437.0
```

Output:

```
0   2015-03-23 04:00:00+00:00
1   2015-03-24 05:00:00+00:00
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

And then:

```
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df.loc['2015']
```

gives

```
                           1day_active_users
time                                        
2015-03-23 04:00:00+00:00            19687.0
2015-03-24 05:00:00+00:00            19437.0
```