# processing timestamps in different formats in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Consider this simple example

```
import pandas as pd

mydf = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['Tue, 27 Jul 2021 06:43:18 +0000',
                            'Sun, 20 Jun 2021 17:00:17 GMT',
                            'Wed, 28 Jul 2021 08:44:00 -0400']})

mydf
Out[50]: 
                         timestamp
0  Tue, 27 Jul 2021 06:43:18 +0000
1    Sun, 20 Jun 2021 17:00:17 GMT
2  Wed, 28 Jul 2021 08:44:00 -0400
```

I am trying to convert all the timestamps to GMT and get rid of the timezone offset.
Unfortunately, the usual solution does not work

```
pd.to_datetime(mydf['timestamp']).dt.tz_localize(None)
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

What is the issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your function call is not able to convert the `mydf['timestamp']` into `datetime` object but plain object and therefore, when you try to access `.dt`, it complains.

You can use the flag `utc=True` to do time-zone aware conversion.

```
pd.to_datetime(mydf['timestamp'], utc=True).dt.tz_localize(None)
```

Comment: This question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326801/pd-to-datetime-returns-an-object-not-a-time-series