# Preserve timezone for pandas.Series.dt.time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, series

I have a list of string representation of timezone-aware times, such as `["15:44:41.012955-04:00", "16:24:41.123456-05:00"]`, where the timezones are not guaranteed to be the same for all values.

I want to convert this to a Pandas series of timezone-aware `datetime.time` objects.

However, there are a few issues:

`pd.to_datetime(...).dt.time()` does not work for mixed types. For example, when using a list of time strings can include `None` or times of varying timezones, `pd.to_datetime()` will convert it to a series with `dtype` `object` (instead of `datetime64`) where the underlying values are `pd.Timestamp()`.

```
# The timezones are different
> ser = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(["15:44:41.012955-04:00", "16:24:41.123456-05:00"]), format="%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
0    1900-01-01 15:44:41.012955-04:00
1    1900-01-01 16:24:41.123456-05:00
dtype: object

> ser.dt.time
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

The other issue is `datetime.time` objects in the series produced by `pd.to_datetime(...).dt.time` do not have the timezone.

```
> ser = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(["15:44:41.012955-10:00", "16:24:41.123456-10:00"]), format="%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
0   1900-01-01 15:44:41.012955-10:00
1   1900-01-01 16:24:41.123456-10:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-600)]

> ser.dt.time
0    15:44:41.012955
1    16:24:41.123456
dtype: object
```

How can I get a series of timezone-aware `datetime.time` objects when passing in a list of string times where the times can have mixed timezones or be `None`.

Comment: `to_datetime` returns object dtype when there are mixed timezones. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326801/pd-to-datetime-returns-an-object-not-a-time-series/58327579#58327579).

Comment: You can parse to datetime with `utc=True`, then set the actual time zone (e.g. `.dt.tz_convert("America/New_York")`, after that, dt accessor will work