# Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values after upgrading pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I recently did a `pip3 install --upgrade pandas` and I'm now using version `1.3.5`. Previously, I was using `0.24.X` IIRC (not sure how to check).

Ever since the update, the simulation code I have is seeing errors like

```
raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")
```

.

Is this a known issue in recent versions of pandas?

The line that's failing is:

```
df["time"] = df.time.dt.tz_convert(local_timezone)
```

I checked the `dtype` of `df` and it shows `time` as `object`, strangely.

The line prior to the above is a merge:

```
  df = pd.merge(
    df,
    another_df[["time", some other columns]],
    on=["time"],
    how="left",
  )
```

I printed the `dtype` of `df.time` and `another_df.time` before the merge and they're both `datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]`, so I'm not sure how the merge ended up making `time` have `dtype=object`. I think this might be a separate issue from the above, but related.

Comment: Maybe related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326801/pd-to-datetime-returns-an-object-not-a-time-series/58327579#58327579)

Comment: @QuangHoang do you know how I can check what previous version of pandas I had? I want to see if I can reproduce this error on my previous version but I can't remember exactly what I had

Comment: @QuangHoang, your related [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326801/pd-to-datetime-returns-an-object-not-a-time-series/58327579#58327579) solved my problem.  This issue only appeared to me after upgrading to 2.2

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once I upgraded to the latest Pandas.
The code line (shown below) started to fail with `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values.`

```py
df_trades['Days Held'] = (df_trades['Exit Date'] - df_trades['Date']).dt.days
```

My workaround was to use lambda and change the line to:

```py
df_trades['Days Held'] = (df_trades['Exit Date'] - df_trades['Date']).apply(lambda x: x.days)
```

I found the workaround/solution (and further explanation) from stefansimik here:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26285